# play store app publishing taking more than 3 days to upload

Tags: android

I published an app on play store, it shows pending publication since 3 days and now I updated with new version code, why my taking this much of time and this is my first app please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns the policies and procedures of app distribution services, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

When you select timed publishing, your update needs to be processed before it can go live. Processing takes up to a few hours.

When your update is processed, you'll see a Go live button. When you select Go live, you'll make the update available on Google Play within a few minutes.

Tip: Timed publishing can be helpful if you want to publish an app update at a specific time for an ad campaign, launch event, or to coordinate a new APK release with changes to your app’s store listing or distribution.

Important notes about timed publishing
Timed publishing is only available for updates, not when publishing an app for the first time.
For certain developer accounts, we’ll take more time to thoroughly review your app(s) to help better protect users. You’ll receive a notification on your app's Dashboard about how long this should take. We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period of at least three days between submitting your app and going live.
You can't revert changes made in timed publishing mode. This is particularly important when publishing new APKs and managing APK version codes.
If you make changes to your app's In-app products page, update prices, or add release notes to your app’s “What’s new in this release?” section while you're in timed publishing mode, they'll be published immediately.
All other updates, including updates submitted using the Google Play Developer API, will be published only after you click Go live.

Answer (score 1):

It can take up to 7 days now. Got this response from Chip at Google Play Developer Support, Please also note that even internal testing won't be available.

> Thank you for contacting Google Play Developer Support regarding your pending review for your internal test track for your app com.mutualtransferapp!
>
> This is a known issue with the opt-in url being available before the internal test track review is completed.
>
> Our engineering teams are working on resolving this issue and we sincerely apologize for the confusion caused.
>
> While the situation is currently evolving, app review times may fluctuate, and may take 7 days or longer.
>
> Moving forward, we recommend you adjust your planning to account for this and avoid resubmitting, as each update or change to your app will cause the review process to start over from the very beginning. We understand the inconvenience this may cause and thank you for your patience and understanding.
>
> Please refrain from submitting any new updates and check back on December 30th to access your internal test.